# How to know DB2 flavour by JDBC connection

Tags: jdbc, db2

I have JDBC connection of DB2, how to identify this is Z/OS390 or AS400 or UDB connection.

Is there any schema which will give idea about type of DB2?

Comment: At the present time, I don't think there is one well known SQL for this. IBM should really address that. Each platform has its own distinct non-portable method to determine version/instance-level information. You might use heuristics.  Db2 for Z may have a sysibm.locations table (not present in the other two platforms). i-series will have QSYS2.TABLES (not present in the other two platforms). LUW will have TABLE  (sysproc.env_get_inst_info())

Comment: For ZOS is there any other way to find other than sysibm.locations table?
For UDB I am using "SELECT TABNAME FROM SYSCAT.TABLES WHERE 1>9", is this correct?

Comment: If you are happy to use a java method (as distinct from only SQL) then the answer from mustaccio should suffice because the returned productname is set by Db2, to one of SQL* (for Linux/Unix/Windows), DSN* for Z/OS, QSQ* for i-series, ARI* for vse/vm.  This appears to answer your question.  For non-java languages, this information is also in the SQLCA.SQLERRP for type-1 connects, and is also accessible in routines via GET DIAGNOSTICS....DB2_PRODUCT_ID .

Answer (score 1):

How to know which flavor of Db2 server you are connected to using JDBC is documented by IBM [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=methods-databasemetadata-identifying-type-data-server). As you can see it is from the *Db2 from z/OS guide*, haven't found it documented elsewhere.

Assuming you have extracted a [DatabaseMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) object using
[Connection.getMetaData()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#getMetaData()), then you can do as follows:

```java
String databaseProductName = databaseMetaData.getDatabaseProductName();
String databaseProductVersion = databaseMetaData.getDatabaseProductVersion();
String databaseProductNameLower = databaseProductName.toLowerCase(Locale.US);


// Detect IBM Db2 flavors
// According to IBM's documentation the database engine must be detected
// primarily from the ProductVersion value whereas IBM makes no real 
// promise on the value of the ProductName. This is why we use the ProductName
// with some caution below.
if (databaseProductNameLower.equals("db2") 
 || databaseProductNameLower.matches("db2[.-/ ].*")) {
    if (databaseProductVersion != null && databaseProductVersion.length() > 3) {
        String ppp = databaseProductVersion.substring(0, 3);
        switch (ppp) {
            case "DSN":
                return DB2_ZOS;  // Db2 for z/OS
            case "SQL":
                return DB2_LUW;  // Db2 on Linux, UNIX, and Windows systems
            case "QSQ":
                return DB2_I;    // Db2 for IBM i 
            case "ARI":
                return DB2_VM;   // Db2 Server for VM and VSE
            default:
        }
    }
}
```

(In my case I use the above as part of something bigger so not returning a value from the above is acceptable. YMMV)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DatabaseMetaData.getDatabaseProductName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getDatabaseProductName()) and [`DatabaseMetaData.getDatabaseProductVersion()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getDatabaseProductVersion()). For example, on Linux for Db2 10.5 fix pack 7 they return `DB2/LINUXX8664` and `SQL10057` respectively.

Sample code:

```
import java.sql.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        if (args.length == 0 ) {
            System.out.println("need url");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String url = args[0];

        try {
            Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            if (c != null) {
                DatabaseMetaData meta = c.getMetaData();
                if (meta != null) {
                    System.out.println( String.format(
                        "Connected to %s %s (%d.%d)",
                        meta.getDatabaseProductName(),
                        meta.getDatabaseProductVersion(),
                        meta.getDatabaseMajorVersion(),
                        meta.getDatabaseMinorVersion()
                        )
                    );
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Metadata is null");
                }
            }
            c.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it is not fulfilling my requirement.
Product name is feed by user in that case how to identify.